# Insert from multiple rows and update some static values at the same time?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to insert some rows form a select statement. The select statement returns multiple rows but with each row insert I want to update a few other columns.

This is what I have so far

```
INSERT INTO {$this->db->dbprefix('term_response')}
SET `Crs Code` = (
   SELECT `Crs Code`
   FROM {$this->db->dbprefix('EnrolmentsList')}
   WHERE `Person ID` = ?
),`term_id` = ?, `st_id` = ?
```

I'm getting 'Subquery returns more than 1 row'. Can I not do what I'm trying?

Thanks

Comment: You have to have only one returned row in the subquery result

Comment: is there now way of updating the affected rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to insert static values for other fields you could do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO {$this->db->dbprefix('term_response')}
SELECT `Crs Code`, 'my term_id value', 'my st_id value'
FROM {$this->db->dbprefix('EnrolmentsList')}
WHERE `Person ID` = 12345;
```

Comment: GOLD, BLOODY, STAR! Thank you!